# Trouble using LDAP Content Synchronization Control / Sync Request Control

Tags: .net, apacheds

I'm trying to use the .net System.DirectoryServices.Protocols libraries to sync against an ApacheDS Ldap server using the LDAP Content Synchronization Control ([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4533#section-2.2)) so that only changes since the last sync are returned.

My first search request, with no cookie value works fine, and I can get a cookie value out of the search response. But when I make a subsequent search request and try to pass the previous sync cookie, I get a Server Unavailable exception when trying to send the request.

Here are some snippets of the code I'm working with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //LdapConnection, binding, etc removed for brevity

    string contentSynchronizationControlOID = "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1";
    string syncDoneControlOID = "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.3";
    byte[] value = GetSyncControlValue();
    DirectoryControl syncRequestControl = new DirectoryControl(contentSynchronizationControlOID, value, true, true);
    syncRequest.Controls.Add(syncRequestControl);

    SearchResponse syncResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(syncRequest);
    foreach (var responseControl in syncResponse.Controls)
    {
        if (responseControl.Type == syncDoneControlOID)
        {
            SaveSyncControlCookie(responseControl.GetValue());
        }
    }
}


private static byte[] GetSyncControlValue()
{
    byte[] value = null;
    try
    {
        value = File.ReadAllBytes("cookie.bin");
    }
    catch { }

    if (value == null)
    {
        return value; 
    }
    else
    {
        object[] controlParts = new object[] { 1, value, false };
        value = BerConverter.Encode("{iob}", controlParts);
    }

    return value;
}

private static void SaveSyncControlCookie(byte[] value)
{
    byte[] result = null;
    object[] controlParts = BerConverter.Decode("{B}", value);

    result = (byte[])controlParts[0];

    if (result != null)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes("cookie.bin", result);
    }

}
```

I've tried with different formats for the BerConverter Encode/Decode methods but haven't had any luck with other combinations.

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being the format string when using BerConverter.Encode to create the sync control value which is sent to the ldap server with the search request.

Switching it from "{iob}" to "{eob}" solved the issue. My guess is that "i" is used to represent regular integer values, and "e" should used when the int value is a value of an enumeration? Not really sure, but it's working for me now =]